# Can we override Azure DevOps variable groups values from a file input

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I have a complete CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps and its working perfectly. now i have a JSON file including the version number for the release.

I need to get this version number as a global variable. How to assign file value to a global variable. I need to use this release no as my build pipeline id, docker tag and release pipeline id.

Comment: Hi, how the things going now? Could you override the variable group value with a file input successfully? Please mark the correct answer as solved or leave a comment if you are still facing some issues thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to set a global variable is:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=name;]value
```

So you can write a PowerShell script that read the release version from the JSON file and set the variable, for example:

```
$jsonFile = Get-Content path/to/json
$json = $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$version = $json.release.version
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=releaseVersion;]$version"
```

Now you can use the variable `$(version)` in your docker tag, etc.

Answer (score 0):

just to add to existing answer, here's how you set build id to the calculater value (because you cannot set it before the build starts, as it is only calculated during the build):

```
- pwsh: Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]${env:VERSION}"
```

assuming `version` is how you called your variable.

Comment: Can we use this code inside the azure-pipeline.yml or do we need this as a separate one?

Comment: you can use it inside existing pipeline definition